# How to automate downloading of well known software on a machine via automation

Tags: automation

So in our project i see we need to create virtual machines for test purposes. These machines need to be installed with latest versions of software such as browsers(chrom,firefox), adobe flash player, java runtime etc

Since this is a repetitive job i was wondering if the downloading can be automated.
I am wondering if i need to write a web crawler kind of script to do that or are there easily available alternatives?

Comment: Why not install everything once on a VM and then duplicate that VM image to other instances?

Comment: That wont help. Because i might need the latest version / different versions on diff VMs.